# extending for loop with exit in bash commands

Tags: bash

I am trying to run multiple loops in bash. For example there are 3 file formats `f1=*.txt` `f2=*.png` and `f3=*.jpg`

and i am trying to give the three different commands for each as

```
for f1 in *.txt; do echo $f1; command 
exit 0

for f2 in *.png; do echo $f2; command
exit 0

for f3 in *.jpg; do echo $f3; command
exit 0
```

but no success, I am getting a broken syntax. I replaced exit 0 with && but no success. Any idea?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying here

Answer (score 3):

Loops in bash terminate with `done`, not `exit`.

```
for f1 in *.txt; do  # loop starts here
  echo $f1
  command 
done                 # loop ends here

# or keep everything on the same line
for f2 in *.png; do echo $f2; command; done
```

You can still use `exit` to exit from your script completely, but `done` is the expected way to signal the end of a loop begun with `for`, `while`, or `until`.

Other shell constructs have their own terminator, like `fi` to terminate `if`, and `esac` to terminate `case`.

See more about loop syntax [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should be using:

```
for file in *.txt; do echo $file; echo command $file; done
for file in *.png; do echo $file; echo command $file; done
for file in *.jpg; do echo $file; echo command $file; done
```

Or variations on that theme.  You can use `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` if you prefer.